# Codeception web driver (Selenium on Docker) tests not working as unable to see other containers (works on my dev machine though?!)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker, docker-compose, codeception

I've got a docker compose setup that allows me to run codeception tests within Docker containers, including a Selenium hub & Chrome node.  The tests all run fine on my local (Mac) dev machine, however when I run them on my (Ubuntu) Gitlab runner the tests are failing, as the selenium chrome node browser is reporting `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, for some reason, and I can't work out why.

My docker composer file…

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:

  composer:
    image:      registry.gitlab.com/project/api-docker-php:prod
    entrypoint:
    - php
    - -d
    - memory_limit=-1
    - /usr/local/bin/composer
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer:/.composer
      - .:/var/www/html

  php:
    image:  registry.gitlab.com/project/api-docker-php:prod
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  nginx:
    image:  cubicmushroom/nginx-letsencrypt
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

  mongo:
    image:  mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - project_api_mongodb_data:/data/db


volumes:
  project_api_mongodb_data: ~
```

And my dev override file…

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '2'

services:

  certs:
    image:    nginx
    command:  >
      openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256
          -subj "/C=UK/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Manchester/O=Cubic Mushroom Ltd./OU=HQ/CN=*.project.dev"
          -keyout /work/privkey.pem -out /work/fullchain.pem
    volumes:
      - project-dev-certs:/work

  php:
    image:  registry.gitlab.com/project/api-docker-php:dev
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=project.dev"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    volumes_from:
      - php
    volumes:
      - project-dev-certs:/etc/letsencrypt/live/project.dev
      - ./conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./conf/nginx/conf.d/default.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./conf/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

  mongo:
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  selenium_hub:
    image:  selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  selenium_node_chrome:
    image:  selenium/node-chrome-debug
    expose:
      - "5555"
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - no_proxy=localhost
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
    links:
      - "selenium_hub:hub"
      - "nginx:api.project.local"

  selenium_node_firefox:
    image:  selenium/node-firefox-debug
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - no_proxy=localhost
    links:
      - "selenium_hub:hub"
      - "nginx:api.project.local"

volumes:
  project-dev-certs: ~
```

Here's my codeception acceptance.suite.yml if it helps too…

```
# acceptance.suite.yml
class_name: AcceptanceDude
modules:
  enabled:
    - MongoDb
    - WebDriver:
        # Uses link alias as defined on selenium_node_chrome & selenium_node_firefox containers in docker compose
        # override files
        url:      'http://api.project.local/app_test.php/'
        browser:  chrome
        host:     selenium_hub
        port:     4444
    - \Project\Common\Test\Helper\Fixtures:
        depends:  Symfony
    - \Project\SymfonyBundle\CalculationBundle\Test\Helper\CalculationRecords:
        depends:  MongoDb
    - \Project\SymfonyBundle\ModuleBundle\Test\Helper\QuestionRecords:
        depends:  MongoDb
    - \Project\SymfonyBundle\UserBundle\Test\Helper\UserAuthentication:
        depends:    Symfony
        web_driver: WebDriver
    - \Project\Tests\Helper\WebDriverSymfonyCompanion:
        depends:
          - Symfony
          - WebDriver
```

And finally, the first few lines of the test that's failing…

```
// codeceptionTestCept.php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

use Codeception\Scenario;
use Project\SymfonyBundle\ManagementBundle\Test\AcceptanceDude;
use Project\SymfonyBundle\UserBundle\DataFixtures\MongoDB\ProjectAdminUser;

/** @var Scenario $scenario */

$I = new AcceptanceDude($scenario);
$I->wantTo('add a calculation to a module');

$I->loadFixtures(['@ManagementBundle:LoadModules.php', '@UserBundle:ProjectAdminUser.php']);
$I->amLoggedInAs(ProjectAdminUser::EMAIL, ProjectAdminUser::PASSWORD);
$I->amOnRoute('project_admin_get_module', ['slug' => 'community']);
$I->seeCurrentRouteIs('project_admin_get_module', ['slug' => 'community']);
```

I can't work out why Docker is behaving differently in the 2 different environments, as I thought it was supposed to insulate all things from the outside world.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

For reference, here are my docker versions…

```
# Local dev machine…
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1

# Gitlab runner…
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my Nginx container was dependant on my dev ssl certificates, which I'd generated on my dev machine, but not on my CI server… so was stopping straight after starting.

No wonder the selenium node couldn't see it!!!

Comment: That was difficult to troubleshoot in IRC but glad you found out.